# Seeing examples of directives used as controllers

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am reading this article: http://icelab.com.au/articles/an-all-in-one-directive-controller-with-angularjs/

I think it would be a better practice to use a controller with ng-template in this example, as I see nothing here that is altering the DOM.

Why is the author using directive?

If you think this is a bad practice, could you elaborate more as to why?

Comment: Inserting elements is not altering the DOM tree???

Comment: Right, this could be done with ng-include and a controller. Why create a directive?

Comment: You wouldn't have an isolate scope, e.g.

Comment: @zeroflagL- so you are saying, if you need to use isolate scope, or other compilation features provided, it makes sense to use directive

Answer (score 0):

The idea is that it's completely modular and can be easily included in other Angular apps. The whole point is that it's acting as a "widget."

While it's great to keep DOM manipulation contained in directives (this is for easy testing), it doesn't mean you can't make non-DOM related directives. In fact, it's common to have large directives that have absolutely no bearing on the UI whatsoever. For example, a directive that handles local-storage or cookies.

It is worth mentioning directives have to be stamped out from the DOM in the first place (via attribute, element, class, etc.). This the idea of the declarative model.

Comment: Hi Anitga... hmmm I have to say I respectfully disagree.  The Angular framework is very clear you are not to alter the DOM in a controller. Shouldn't the use of directive be restricted to DOM only manipulation?

Comment: Hi @koolunix. I never said you should be manipulating the DOM from a controller. I said that directives aren't *just* for DOM manipulation. So "Shouldn't the use of directive be restricted to DOM only manipulation?" is certainly incorrect. Even Angular's own built-in directives are often non-DOM related.

Comment: Hi @Anitga- I guess what I mean is- Angular is very strict about not manipulating DOM anywhere else but a directive- conversely, should not it be just as strict about how directive is used? I understand what you mean. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @koolunix I understand what you're saying, but the reverse of it is simply not the case. Angular directives are not just for DOM stuff. They often have no DOM component whatsoever, and this is a standard in both the community and on the core Angular team.

Comment: Directives are inherently DOM related.

Comment: @zeroflagL No argument there. You need to stamp them out from the DOM. That's intentional. It's the whole point of the declarative model.

Comment: Then what exactly do you mean by _non-DOM related_?

Comment: @zeroflagL I mean not "manipulating" the DOM in the way that the OP is using on the basis on the question. We're getting into awkward semantics now. My point was you can make directives that you still need to stamp out from the DOM to bring in additional functionality that isn't necessarily reflected on the screen.